# How to check for filters in excel worksheet and clear them using python?

Tags: python, excel

How do I check if a column in an excel worksheet has a filter and then clear the filter from the column using python?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean autofilter, there can only be one on the Sheet...

**Openpyxl** something like following should be sufficient;

```
import openpyxl


wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('foo.xlsx')
ws = wb['Sheet1']

if ws.auto_filter:
    print(f'Sheet has autofilter in range {ws.auto_filter.ref}')
    ws.auto_filter.ref = None

wb.save('foo.xlsx')
```

**Xlwings** you can use the following;

```
import xlwings as xw

with xw.App(visible=False) as app:
    wb = xw.Book('foo.xlsx')
    ws = wb.sheets('Sheet1')

    if ws.api.AutoFilter:
        print(f'Sheet has autofilter in range {ws.api.AutoFilter.Range.Address}')
        ws.api.AutoFilterMode = False

    wb.save('foo.xlsx')
```

**Win32com**, similar to Xlwings;

```
import win32com.client as win32

xl = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Excel.Application")
xl.Visible = False

wb = xl.Workbooks.Open('<path>/foo.xlsx')

ws = wb.Sheets('Sheet1')
print()
if ws.AutoFilterMode:
    print(f'Sheet has autofilter in range {ws.AutoFilter.Range.Address}')
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False

wb.Save()
# wb.SaveAs('<path>/foo2.xlsx')  # Or save as another workbook
```

Comment: None of these work for some strange reason

Comment: Does the print statement return any range? Provide more detail on the filters, how are they created what does it look like, you can post a screenshot. Does clicking the 'filter' icon in the Data tab in Excel clear the filter?

Comment: the print statement only works for the xlwings program and not the others. Yes, clicking the 'filter' icon in the Data tab in Excel clears the filter.

Comment: Ok, so looks like standard autofilter but can't see much more without the looking at the workbook itself, unless you can provide steps on how the filter is added to a Sheet that reproduces the issue. You could also try running the filter clear statement for Openpyxl and Win32com without the criteria check since if the print statement is not executed then the criteria is failing for some reason and the statement to clear the filter is not executed either.

Comment: i tried filter clear and it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

works with the code below:

```
import xlwings as xw

wb = xw.Book('foo.xlsx')
ws = wb.sheets('Sheet1')    

def remove_filter():
  if ws.api.AutoFilter:
       print("yes")
       ws.api.AutoFilter.ShowAllData()
  return None
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).